# Filtering records in Shopify API based on order_number

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to filter records in Shopify API based on the order_number? I did not see anything for this in the docs. I also tried /admin/orders.json?order_number=1001, but it returns all the records.

However, I do see that the "order_number" is the same as the "name" parameter. Would this always be the case? If so, can I filter using the name parameter instead of the order_number?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can rely on `name` and `order_number` being the same.  Therefore, in order to fetch an order by `order_number`, you can query for `"/admin/orders.json?status=any&name=%23" + order_number`.  The `%23` represents the `#` prepended to the number in `name`.  You probably also want to keep the `status=any` in there because by default it uses `status=open`, which would ignore your order if it's been closed/cancelled, thereby falsely indicating that no order exists by the name.

Comment: You cannot rely on `name` and `order_number` being the same. `name` does contain the `order_number` but may also have a configured prefix and suffix.

Answer (score 0):

There's no filtering on order number, but you can filter on order IDs.

For a specific list of orders:

```
/admin/orders.json?ids=401229020,397704404,357704404
```

For a range:

```
/admin/orders.json?since_id=397704404&limit=50
```

Comment: I don't need id based filtering. Will name and order_number always be the same? Basically I'll get the order_number as input, and I need to fetch information for that particular order number.